# return data from showModalDialog

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I would like to continue working with the data from the ModalDialog in the function abfrage().It is important that I get the data there I want to return it.i would like to create a loop with several input fields later on html, so i don't write this on the html page.

```
function abfrage(){
  let count = 1;
  let html = '<input type="text" name="text">';
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('dialogForm');
  let dialog = ui.showModalDialog(t.evaluate(), 'Hello');
}
```

#### dialogForm.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top">
      </head>
      <body>
      <h1>Userform</h1>
        <table>
        <?!= html ?>
        </table>
        <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" >
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="action">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Try using <form> tag <input type=“button” ... onclick=“processForm(this.parentNode);” \> and then in js use google.script.run.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean

Answer (score 0):

gs:

```
function abfrage(){
  let count = 1;
  let html = '<form><br /><input type="text" name="text">';
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('dialogForm');
  let dialog = ui.showModalDialog(t.evaluate(), 'Hello');
}

function serversidefunctionname(obj) {
  var name=obj.name;
  //process name
  //return html if desired 
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top">
      </head>
      <body>
      <h1>Userform</h1>
        <?!= html ?>
        <br /><input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" >
        <br /><input type="button" value="Submit" class="action" onClick="processForm(this.parentNode);" /> 
      </form>
      <script>
        function processForm(obj) {
          google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(function(retobj){
            //process return from server side function if any
          })
          .serversidefunctionname(obj);
        }
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Interesting approach. do you somehow have a chance to do this in abfrage()?

Comment: Didn't  I just  do it in there?